# upload corrected version to github

Tags: git, github

I spent considerable time downloading the following code.

https://github.com/contextio/Python-ContextIO

I will like to add the following line to the readme in order to make it clear that this is not the latest version.

```
This is compatible with older api 1.1 for the latest one use ContextIO2 repository.
```

newbie questions:

How do I make the change and push it up?

Will the owner accept this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fork the repository, make the change on the forked repo, and then submit a pull request. [This](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) should help you out.